# Why won't the WordPress editor make changes to html page with custom template?

Tags: wordpress, templates, editor

I had created a custom page-Contact.php file to use as the template for the contact page of my website.

When adding short code (or any text at all) to the WordPress editor in my WordPress admin section, no updates were being made to the html after inspection of the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem, but it was a little tough for me as a beginner to find the answer so I'll post it again in hopes of helping someone else.

Add the loop!

All pages need a loop in order to display any info/changes from the visual editor.